# What can lead to disappointed and angry stakeholders?

Tags: scrum, scrum-master, stakeholders, sprint-review

> At the fifth Sprint Review, the stakeholders seem disappointed and
>   angry. When asked about it, they say the product or system as being
>   built will not meet their needs and will cost more than they
>   anticipated spending, What led to this? (Choose best two answers)
>
> A) The stakeholders haven’t been using the Sprint Reviews to actively
>   engage , and inspect and evaluate progress
>
> B) Changes to the project plan were not adequately documented and
>   shared. The change request procedure was not diligently followed
>
> C) The PMO and its project managers have not been engaged adequately
>   causing the project plan to become inaccurate
>
> D) The Product Owner has not been interacting frequently with
>   stakeholders keeping them aware of the progress.
>
> E) The stakeholders were not allowed to attend daily scrum
>
> F) The scrum master has not ensured transparency

Which are the correct two answers?

Comment: Given that this is a test question, the answer depends more on the test creator's prejudice than on the practice of project management.  If stakeholders are unhappy during a project review, then the PM has failed to communicate.  The rest is details.  I would have picked C, but that depends on assumptions about "the PMO" (project/program/portfolio)

Comment: Homework or exam?

Answer (score 8):

Choosing two answers, I would select A and D.

B can be eliminated since project plans and formal change request procedures aren't typically a part of agile delivery approaches. Agile Software Development favors collaboration and responding to change over long-term plans. Frequent delivery of working software and responding to change builds a change request procedure into the methods.

C can also be eliminated for similar reasons. Agile methods aren't about engaging the PMO and project managers, but engaging with stakeholders. These could be customers, users, user representatives, or other people with knowledge of what the stakeholders need and want.

E is inconsistent with Scrum. The Daily Scrum is an event for the Development Team. The purpose of the Daily Scrum is to allow the Development Team to inspect the work that they have done and the progress toward the Sprint Goals. The problem appears to be more centered around the ordering of the work and the selection of the Sprint Goals, and the Daily Scrum is too late to be addressing these.

F could be a possible answer, but the wording is a bit off and it's not my favorite. Typically, the Scrum Master doesn't ensure anything. The Scrum Master helps the Scrum Team ensure appropriate visibility of the work and works with stakeholders to help them understand the way the team is working and how to be effective in an Agile environment.

A represents a true statement about Scrum. The purpose of the Sprint Review is for stakeholders and the Scrum Team to interact. The stakeholders should be present to provide feedback on the work that has been done. Another outcome would be a reordered Product Backlog that represents anything that has been learned or has changed in the environment. Of course, you can't say that it is true unless you've attended the first four Sprint Reviews, this definitely seems like something that could contribute to disappointment, anger, and frustration among the stakeholders.

D is another possibly answer. One of the principles of Agile Software Development is frequent interactions between developers and the business. This is often expanded to the developing organization and the stakeholders. One would expect that the Product Owner, and as appropriate, all members of the Scrum Team, would be interacting with stakeholders to understand their needs and how to best satisfy them. Insufficient interaction and understanding can definitely lead to disappointment and frustration among the stakeholders.

A, D, and F are all candidates for answers. I dislike the wording of both D and F, but I dislike the wording of F more than D. So I'd select A and D as my choices, but I wouldn't have a strong argument about F either.

Comment: I’d go with A & D. While the Scrum Master may not have been refereeing the process as well as possible, stakeholder management is primarily the PO’s job, and the Sprint Review Is the dedicated event for stakeholders to provide product feedback to the whole team.

Comment: What about the cost complaint? Where in Scrum do costs come in?

Comment: @DavidEspina In Scrum cost is fixed per Sprint, usually. It all goes back to inspection and adaptation in the Sprint Review to make sure that what was done is right and what is going to be done next aligns with needs and expectations. If, after 5 Sprints, the stakeholders aren't getting the right thing, they are going to need more Sprints to correct the problem(s), hence costing too much. In short, I don't think the cost matters as much as making sure the work is understood and the most valuable work is done first.

Comment: Okay, got it.  Thanks, @thomas

Answer (score -5):

Most likely (E) but it could be bigger than that.

These stakeholder concerns could be originating from one or several legitimate concerns:  lack of communication, perception of scope creep, lack of visible progress and so on.

Always remember that "stakeholders" are not computer programmers – they are businesspeople.  They don't closely understand what your team is doing nor how exactly they are doing it, and they don't have to.  Project management (and their senior managers) should immediately sit down with the stakeholders to try to clear the air.  And, pay *very* close attention to anything which they say which might suggest a change of project schedule and/or focus.  *They are The Almighty Customer.™*

Comment: (E) is the one answer that it can _not_ be (the others are at least remotely plausible to varying degrees) as stakeholders participating at a daily standup completely runs counter to the idea of the daily standup.